# How to config proguard to keep case class use with lift-json?

Tags: android, json, scala, lift, proguard

I want use lift-json on Android to process JSON object.

Code below:

```
case class Msg(a:Int, s:Int)

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val msg = Msg(1, 1)
val jv = Extraction.decompose(m)
println(compact(render(jv))) // this print {}
```

My proguard config is:

```
"-dontoptimize",
"-printseeds keep.log", "-printmapping obf.log",
"-keepparameternames",
"-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses",
"-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers",
"-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod",
"-dontobfuscate",
"-keepclassmembers class * { ** MODULE$; }",
"-keep public class scala.ScalaObject",
"-keep public class scala.Function*",
"-keep public class scala.Tuple2",
"-keep public class scala.Tuple4",
"-keep class my.pkg.**",
"-keep interface my.pkg.**",
"-keepclasseswithmembers class my.pkg.** { *; }"
```

What elements I need keep with lift-json lib?

Comment: Googol Shan, are you saying you succeeded at proguard+lift, even without the JSON package?
I tried but failed. If you can share the SBT config -- it would be great!

Comment: Sorry, I only use lift-json lib, no other lift relative lib.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on the liftweb's google group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb
AFAIK it's the preferred way of the liftweb community. (I don't know if it's appropriate for a single dependency, and maybe someone will answer here.)

Comment: thanks, I am ask this question on google group now. (BTW, lift-json can use as single dependency lib)

Comment: It would certainly help if you explained in what way lift-json fails when proguared with your current configuration.